# "quotaExceeded: Calendar usage limits exceeded" when `sendNotifications` enabled

Tags: google-calendar-api

In my company we set up Google Calendar API to notify our providers when we have new missions to offer them and allow them to accept/refuse mission through the Google Calendar.

However, since last week we started getting `quotaExceeded` errors ("Calendar usage limits exceeded"). I checked quotas but figured out we are way below quotas (3,000 / 1,000,000 requests per day and 10 / 500 requests per 100 seconds).

```
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/svbk5reui******l6h044qn3h4%40group.calendar.google.com/events/1meqllvk6******dt9poej9mk0?alt=json&sendNotifications=true returned "Calendar usage limits exceeded.">
```

After checking a bit further, I noticed there are also ["hidden" quotas](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en). I say "hidden" quotas beacause I can't find any feedback about the evolution of these quotas. I assumed we might have reached either **"Send too many invitations to external guests"** or **"Email too many guests via Google Calendar events"** quota. So I set `sendNotifications=false` where we used to set `sendNotifications=true`.

Since I made this change, we didn't experience the `quotaExceeded` error anymore. However, our providers are also not notified anymore when we offer them a new mission. So, I doubled the API calls with an e-mail sent to the providers including the link to the Google Calendar event.

Yet, now, some of them can't access the link, and the other can't answer if they will be attending the event or not.

How come setting `sendNotifications=false` disallows access or answering to the attendees? Can I check exactly what quotas are exceeded? And what are my solutions to notify our providers about new missions and allow them to see it in their calendar and answer it?

Comment: Checking the [Handle API Errors](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#403_calendar_usage_limits_exceeded), while you've seen the usage limit in the G Suite Administrator help try using a Service Account with authority delegation and exponential backoff.

Comment: Thanks. I already use a Service Account with restrictions on Calendar API only. I guess I'll have to implement an exponential backoff. However, we are going to have more and more providers and I fear the amount of failures is only going to grow up as well, which means delays in calendar updates/notifications.